# Excel Scrolling Marquee vb script not working with formatted text

Tags: excel, vba

We've tried various vb scripts to scroll text in a range of cells in Excel 2010. I found a great one we could tweak but, unfortunately, I can only get this to work with text that has no formatting to it. I also can't seem to get it to repeat the text with no gaps.

I've attached a screen shot of what the text looks like in the format we'd like to scroll it.

It does work with a picture of the copied cells entered into the target range, but, the edge of the excel spreadsheet cuts off the picture scrolling from off screen.

HELP! We're not serious coders by any means. Can anyone point us in the right direction? If it isn't possible, that would be great to know as well.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[scrolling marquee text with formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQNSg.jpg)

```
    Option Explicit

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32" ( _
ByVal hdc As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal hdc As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" _
(ByVal hdc As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32" _
(ByVal hdc As Long, _
ByVal nWidth As Long, _
ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" _
(ByVal hdc As Long, _
ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" _
(ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" _
(ByVal hDestDC As Long, _
ByVal x As Long, _
ByVal y As Long, _
ByVal nWidth As Long, _
ByVal nHeight As Long, _
ByVal hSrcDC As Long, _
ByVal xSrc As Long, _
ByVal ySrc As Long, _
ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ScreenToClient Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long


Private Const SRCCOPY As Long = &HCC0020
Private Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88
Private Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90
Private Const POINTSPERINCH As Long = 72

Private tPrevRect As RECT
Private oTargetCell As Range
Private bStop As Boolean
Private bRangeRectHasChanged As Boolean
Private vNumberFormat As String
Private vHorzAlignment As Long
Private lMemoryDC As Long
Private lWBHwnd As Long
Private i As Long

Public Sub StartScrollingRow()

    '//Scroll the text in Cell Range from Right to Left.
    Call ScrollCell(Range("B4:R4"), 0.01, True)

End Sub

Private Sub TakeCellSnapShot(Target As Range)

    Dim lDC As Long
    Dim lXLDeskhwnd As Long
    Dim lBmp As Long

    '//Get the workbook Wnd hwnd.
    lXLDeskhwnd = _
    FindWindowEx(FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption) _
    , 0, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    lWBHwnd = FindWindowEx _
    (lXLDeskhwnd, 0, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)

    '//Get the Wbk window DC.
    lDC = GetDC(lWBHwnd)

    '//Create a memory DC.
    lMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(lDC)

    '//Get the target cell metrics in pixels.
    tPrevRect = GetRangeRect(ByVal Target)

    With tPrevRect

        '//create a compatible Bmp the same size as the target cell.
        lBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap _
        (lDC, (.Right - 1 - .Left), (.Bottom - .Top))

        '//Select the Bmp onto our mem DC.
        DeleteObject SelectObject(lMemoryDC, lBmp)

        '//Copy the target cell image onto the Mem DC.
        BitBlt lMemoryDC, 0, 0, (.Right - .Left), (.Bottom - .Top), _
        lDC, .Left, .Top, SRCCOPY

    End With

    '//CleanUp.
    ReleaseDC 0, lDC
    ReleaseDC lMemoryDC, 0

End Sub

Private Sub ScrollCell _
(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal Delay As Single, _
Optional ByVal RightToLeft As Boolean)

    '//Make sure the target range is one Cell.
    If Target.Cells.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub

    bStop = False

    '//Store the target cell for later use.
    Set oTargetCell = Target

    '//Unselect the target cell to avoid the selection borders.
    If ActiveCell.Address = _
    Target.Address Then oTargetCell.Offset(1).Select

    If Not bRangeRectHasChanged Then

        vHorzAlignment = Target.HorizontalAlignment

        Target.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

    End If

    '//copy the target cell image onto memory.
    Call TakeCellSnapShot(Target)

    If Not bRangeRectHasChanged Then

        vNumberFormat = Target.NumberFormat

        Target.NumberFormat = ";;;"

        '//call the text scrolling routine.
        Call UpdateCell(Target, Delay, RightToLeft)

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub UpdateCell _
(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal Delay As Single, _
Optional ByVal RightToLeft As Boolean)

    Dim lDC As Long

    '//store the Wbk window DC.
    lDC = GetDC(lWBHwnd)

    '//Scroll the Target Cell Text.
    Do

        '//Do nothing if not on the target sheet.
        If ActiveSheet Is oTargetCell.Parent Then
            '//Update the tPrevRect Struct if the Target Cell
            '//screen location/size have changed.
            If tPrevRect.Left <> GetRangeRect(Target).Left Or _
            tPrevRect.Top <> GetRangeRect(Target).Top Or _
            tPrevRect.Right <> GetRangeRect(Target).Right Or _
            tPrevRect.Bottom <> GetRangeRect(Target).Bottom Then
                bRangeRectHasChanged = True
                tPrevRect = GetRangeRect(Target)
                Target.NumberFormat = vNumberFormat
                ScrollCell oTargetCell, Delay
                Target.NumberFormat = ";;;"
            End If

            '//do the actual text scrolling here.
            With tPrevRect

                If RightToLeft Then
                    BitBlt lDC, .Left + 1, .Top, (.Right - .Left), _
                    (.Bottom - .Top), _
                    lMemoryDC, i - (.Right - .Left), 0, SRCCOPY
                Else
                    BitBlt lDC, .Left, .Top, (.Right - .Left), _
                    .Bottom - .Top, _
                    lMemoryDC, (.Right - .Left) - i, 0, SRCCOPY
                End If

                If i >= (.Right - .Left) * 2 Then i = 0

            End With

            i = i + 1
            SetDelay Delay  'Secs.

        End If

        DoEvents

    Loop Until bStop

    ReleaseDC 0, lDC


End Sub

'//===============================
'// Other Supporting routines...
'//===============================
Private Function ScreenDPI(bVert As Boolean) As Long

    Static lDPI(1), lDC

    If lDPI(0) = 0 Then
        lDC = GetDC(0)
        lDPI(0) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, LOGPIXELSX)
        lDPI(1) = GetDeviceCaps(lDC, LOGPIXELSY)
        lDC = ReleaseDC(0, lDC)
    End If

    ScreenDPI = lDPI(Abs(bVert))

End Function

Private Function PTtoPX _
(Points As Single, bVert As Boolean) As Long

    PTtoPX = Points * ScreenDPI(bVert) / POINTSPERINCH

End Function


Private Function GetRangeRect(ByVal rng As Range) As RECT

    Dim tPt1 As POINTAPI
    Dim tPt2 As POINTAPI
    Dim OWnd  As Window

    On Error Resume Next

    Set OWnd = rng.Parent.Parent.Windows(1)

    With rng
        GetRangeRect.Left = _
        PTtoPX(.Left * OWnd.Zoom / 100, 0) _
        + OWnd.PointsToScreenPixelsX(0)
        GetRangeRect.Top = _
        PTtoPX(.Top * OWnd.Zoom / 100, 1) _
        + OWnd.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)
        GetRangeRect.Right = _
        PTtoPX(.Width * OWnd.Zoom / 100, 0) _
        + GetRangeRect.Left
        GetRangeRect.Bottom = _
        PTtoPX(.Height * OWnd.Zoom / 100, 1) _
        + GetRangeRect.Top
    End With

     With GetRangeRect
         tPt1.x = .Left
         tPt1.y = .Top
         tPt2.x = .Right
         tPt2.y = .Bottom
         ScreenToClient lWBHwnd, tPt1
         ScreenToClient lWBHwnd, tPt2
        .Left = tPt1.x + 2
        .Top = tPt1.y
        .Right = tPt2.x - 2
        .Bottom = tPt2.y
    End With

End Function

Private Sub SetDelay(TimeOut As Single)

    Dim t As Single

    t = Timer

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Timer - t >= TimeOut

End Sub
```

Comment: Is all the text in one cell or is each text item in a different cell?

Comment: And are you saying that you want a range of cells to scroll across your excel worksheet or across your entire screen (including beyond the excel application)?

Comment: Hey @Ambie, each text item is in a different cell and currently scrolls within the target range designated in the script. I adjust that depending on how much data we want to include but, it currently scrolls perfectly within that designated range as needed with non formatted text - except for it not working for formatted text. I  may be the format used to convert the columns to condensed numbers with K or M for thousand or million.